# Share video via facebook sdk 4.x in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to share a video via latest facebook sdk.

I am trying to do that in this way:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
    Uri videoFileUri = Uri.parse(mFileMP4.getAbsolutePath());
    ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
        .build();
    ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(shareVideo)
        .build();

    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

And i am getting this error:

```
com.facebook.a.a﹕ Got unexpected exception: java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
```

Anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: I have this same error, despite I am not sharing anything. I just set the new login widget and is throwing the same error every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting your video uri to a string? Like so:

```
.setLocalUrl(videoFileUri.toString())
```

Comment: Yes, but it cannot be string. It have to be uri.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()

        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()

        .setVideo(video)
        .build();
```

refer this side https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android